# async function not returns value but showing after calling undefined typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Below is my function returning login token when I debug my function it waits until return but when call function returns undefined and errors are also undefined don't know why it's happening

```
import userModel from '../Models/user.model';
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
let token = null;
process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret';


export default class loginController{

    static async login(user:any): Promise<any>{
        try{
              await userModel.findOne({
                  Email: user.Email
                })
                  .then(async (res:any) => {
                    if (user) {
                      if (await bcrypt.compareSync(user.Password, res.Password)) {
                        const payload = {

                          Firstname: res.Firstname,
                          Lastname: res.Lastname,
                          email: res.Email,

                        }

                        token = await jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                          expiresIn: 1400
                        })
                        let decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY)

                        return token;
                      }
                       else {
                        return "Password is Wrong";
                      }

                    } 

                    else {
                        return 'Please Check Username';
                    }

                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                       return('error : ' + err)
                  })
              }  

        catch(err)
        {
            return err
        }
    }
}
```

And my calling function is

```
const router : Router = Router();

router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
       const user = await loginController.login(req.body);
       res.json(user)
   } catch (error) {
       res.json(error)
   }
})
```

I tried call errors it's also debugger waiting until returns value to error but showing undefined

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what parameters are you passing in req.body?

Comment: object of username and password but thats not problem

Comment: but there you are calling email as well               await userModel.findOne({
                  Email: user.Email
                })

Comment: email is username login working perfectly there is no issue with that i am having problem with only return

Comment: then(async (res:any) => { console.log the res here and see the result is getting something or not and its thats ok check this line bcrypt.compareSync(user.Password, res.Password)

Comment: that working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`login` function doesn't return `token` because of function scoping. If you have multiple callbacks you can wrap it with a `new Promise`  and use `resolve` function for returning values.

```
export default class loginController {
  static async login(user: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await userModel
          .findOne({
            Email: user.Email
          })
          .then(async res => {
            if (user) {
              if (await bcrypt.compareSync(user.Password, res.Password)) {
                const payload = {
                  Firstname: res.Firstname,
                  Lastname: res.Lastname,
                  email: res.Email
                };

                const token = await jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                  expiresIn: 1400
                });
                let decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);

                resolve(token);
              } else {
                resolve('Password is Wrong');
              }
            } else {
              resolve('Please Check Username');
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            resolve('error : ' + err);
          });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"If you have multiple callbacks you need to wrap it with a new Promise"* – No! That is the classic *Promise anti-pattern* and it is **bad** advice. You never wrap existing promises in a new promise, if you have multiple callbacks you *chain* them. That's what promises were designed for. It's also a bad idea to mix `async-await` with explicit promises, it's just confusing and prone to errors.

Comment: @Lennholm you are right about mixing `async-await` with promises. But it's also a bad idea mix `async-await` with `then-catch`. To be honest this code is already too messed up and I didn't want to edit code a lot because it's not related with question.

Comment: @NisanCoskun if you want to edit code you can edit i am fresher so it will be good for me to see my mistakes and actually my code too messed up  thanks